# Searching Sentences in Lucene and getting matched terms

Tags: java, search, indexing, lucene, large-data

I have an application that requires me to index a few gigabytes of sentences(about 16million lines).

Currently my search works in the following way.

My search terms is usually revolving around a phrase. For example "running in the park". I want to be able to search for sentences similar to this or contains part of these phrase. I do so by constructing smaller phrases :

"running in the"
"in the park" etc.

Each of them is given a weight (the longer ones get larget weight)

At the moment, I treat each line as one document. A typical search takes about a few seconds and I am wondering if there is a way to increase the speed of the search.

On top of that, I also need to get what is matched.

For example : "I was jogging in the park this morning" matches "in the park", and I would want to know how it is matched. I know about Explainer for lucene search but is there a simpler way or is there a resource that i can get to learn how to extract the information I want from Lucene's Explainer.

I am currently using regex to get the match term. It is fast but are inaccurate as lucene sometimes ignore punctuations and other stuffs and I can't be handling all the special cases.

Answer (score 3):

Highlighter is better than Explainer, it is faster.
You can extract the matched phrases between tags after high light them.
[Java regex to extract text between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560672/java-regex-to-extract-text-between-tags)

```
public class HighlightDemo {
Directory directory;
Analyzer analyzer;
String[] contents = {"running in the park",
        "I was jogging in the park this morning",
        "running on the road",
        "The famous New York Marathon has its final miles in Central park every year and it's easy to understand why: the park, with a variety of terrain and excellent scenery, is the ultimate runner's dream. With its many paths that range in level of difficulty, Central Park allows a runner to experience clarity and freedom in this picturesque urban oasis."};


@Before
public void setUp() throws IOException {


    directory = new RAMDirectory();
    analyzer = new WhitespaceAnalyzer();

    // indexed documents


    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
    for (int i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new Field("content", contents[i], Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED)); // store & index
        doc.add(new NumericField("id", Field.Store.YES, true).setIntValue(i));      // store & index
        writer.addDocument(doc);
    }
    writer.close();
}

@Test
public void test() throws IOException, ParseException, InvalidTokenOffsetsException {
    IndexSearcher s = new IndexSearcher(directory);
    QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "content", analyzer);
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = parser.parse("park");

    TopDocs hits = s.search(query, 10);
    SimpleHTMLFormatter htmlFormatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter();
    Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(htmlFormatter, new QueryScorer(query));
    for (int i = 0; i < hits.scoreDocs.length; i++) {
        int id = hits.scoreDocs[i].doc;
        Document doc = s.doc(id);
        String text = contents[Integer.parseInt(s.doc(id).get("id"))];

        TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream("content", new StringReader(text));
        org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.TextFragment[] frag = highlighter.getBestTextFragments(tokenStream, text, false, 10);
        for (int j = 0; j < frag.length; j++) {
            if ((frag[j] != null) && (frag[j].getScore() > 0)) {
                assertTrue(frag[j].toString().contains("<B>"));
                assertTrue(frag[j].toString().contains("</B>"));

                System.out.println(frag[j].toString());
            }
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but I really don't want to extract the text between tags.

Answer (score 2):

Lucene's "contrib" module [Highlighter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/contrib-highlighter/index.html) will let you extract what was matched by Lucene.

Comment: How is it done with Highlighter class? As I understood Highlighter is used to highlight matched terms. Can I get output matched terms with Highlighter module?

Comment: I haven't used Highlighter myself, but as I understand Highlighter it uses the search results to find the matched terms to highlight, so the information is already in the search results (I think you have to index the positions for Highlighter to work -- I don't see how Highlighter could work otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

SpanQueries might help you to find where was query matched in sentence:
https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/package-summary.html

Using this you get exact locations from query:
[How to get the matching spans of a Span Term Query in Lucene 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385887/how-to-get-the-matching-spans-of-a-span-term-query-in-lucene-5)