# display exact phrase containing the word given in the solr query

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene

if I have a sentence:

> Lucene is an extremely rich and powerful full-text search library
>   written in Java. You can use Lucene to provide full-text indexing
>   across both database objects and documents in various formats
>   (Microsoft Office documents, PDF, HTML, text, and so on). In this
>   tutorial, we'll go through the basics of using Lucene to add full-text
>   search functionality to a fairly typical J2EE application: an online
>   accommodation database. The main business object is the Hotel class.
>   In this tutorial, a Hotel has a unique identifier, a name, a city, and
>   a description.

If I want to search for java, in query if I give as java, I need the result as:
Lucene is an extremely rich and powerful full-text search library written in Java.

Just the phrase around the given keyword instead of displaying the whole text.

Can that be done? If yes, pleae let me know it in a brief way. I am new to solr

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your requirements, you have a document and you want to get the sentence which contains the matching keyword.

Similar problem is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875604/searching-sentences-in-lucene-and-getting-matched-terms) and working example is given.