# Get content between two tags and then return full string

Tags: java

how can i get some text between each two tags(`<tagname></tagname>`) and after changed the text of these two tags **i need the complete string along with changes**.think,this is the java string content.

**before change**

---

"Lorem ipsum dolor `<tagname>text to be changed 1</tagname>` amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud `<tagname>text to be changed 2</tagname>` laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint `<tagname>text to be changed 3</tagname>` cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

---

**after changed, should be like this**

---

"Lorem ipsum dolor `<tagname>text changed 1</tagname>` amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud `<tagname>text changed 2</tagname>` laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint `<tagname>text changed 3</tagname>` cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

---

actually i need a method like this,

```
String getChangedString(String toBeChanged){
   //process
   return changedString;
}
```

how can i get this.

thanks.

Comment: This would be a good job for a Perl script.

Comment: Your question is actually a bunch of smaller questions. Check out the `String`class. And how does the method know what to set the text to?

Comment: Are you expecting someone to write the code for you? That's not how SO works. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].

Comment: Is this HTML or XML? I am tempted to downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String getChangedString(String toBeChanged){
   String changedString = toBeChanged;

   while (changedString.indexOf("<tagname>") >= 0)
   {
     changedString = changedString.substring(0, changedString.indexOf("<tagname>")) +
       "whatever replacement string" +
       changedString.substring(changedString.indexOf("</tagname>") + "</tagname>".length());
   }


   return changedString;
}
```

Comment: if you work with very large strings, you should look into using the StringBuilder class.

Comment: hey Alex.if i need to edit(not replace ex:like UPPERCASE) inside text of <tagname> how can i achieve this?how can i get text which is inside tags from your method?

Comment: @bews99: changedString.substring(changedString.indexOf("<tagname>") + "<tagname>".length(), changedString.indexOf("</tagname>"))

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the tags are within an XML file, you should use one of the existing XML parsers such as DOM or SAX instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same, maybe this question can help you, take a look:
[Java regex to extract text between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560672/java-regex-to-extract-text-between-tags)

It uses a regular expression to get the text content between tags. In my case, I was interested on getting the text from the first tags found on my xml, not from each tags

Answer (score 1):

There is a flawless string parsing based utility available in org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils, below code worked perfectly for me.

```
String title = StringUtils.substringBetween(testHtml, "<title>", "</title>");
System.out.println("title:" + title); // good
```