# Get specific text from a .txt file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I want to get information from a script so i used this function

```
public static HashMap<String, String> getEnvVariables(String scriptFile,String config) {
    HashMap<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try {

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(scriptFile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String strLine;
                          String var= "if [ \"$1\" = \""+config +"\" ] ; then";
        // Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // use a Scanner to parse the content of each line
            // exclude concatenated variables (export xx:$xx)
            if (strLine.startsWith("export") && !strLine.contains("$")) {
                strLine = strLine.substring(7);
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(strLine);
                scanner.useDelimiter("=");
                if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    String name = scanner.next();
                    String value = scanner.next();
                    System.out.println(name+"="+value);
                    vars.put(name, value);
                }
            }
        }
```

However i want to begin reading from a particular line which is

```
if [ \"$1\" = \""+config +"\" ] ; then
```

the problem is that when a line begins with a space the program considers that the file have ended ! 
So how can i fix it and make the program pars to the end of file ?
considering that the line could begin with more thant one space 
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which i share with you .

```
public static HashMap<String, String> getEnvVariables(String scriptFile ,String config1,String config2) {
    HashMap<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(scriptFile);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String strLine = null;
        String stopvar = config2;
        String startvar =config1;
        String keyword = "set";
        do {
            if (strLine != null && strLine.contains(startvar)) {
                if (strLine.contains(stopvar)) {
                    return vars;
                }
                while (strLine != null && !strLine.contains(stopvar)) {
                    strLine = br.readLine();
                    if (strLine.trim().startsWith(keyword)&& !strLine.contains("$")) {
                        strLine = strLine.trim().substring(keyword.length())
                        .trim();
                        String[] split = strLine.split("=");
                        String name = split[0];
                        String value = split[1];
                        System.out.println(name + "=" + value);
                        vars.put(name, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        } while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Status status = new Status(Status.ERROR, Activator.PLUGIN_ID,
                IStatus.ERROR, e.getMessage(), e);
        Activator.getDefault().getLog().log(status);
    }
    return vars;
}
```

thanks for helping !

Answer (score 2):

You may try to trim the irrelevant spaces from every line ?

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine().trim()) != null) {...}
```

Edit : don't do that (thanks Joop Eggen!) or you'll have a nice NPE...). Try:

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    strLine = strLine.trim();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Good idea, one often forgets the simple `.trim()`. Though do it inside `{ ... }` as you still have not tested for strLine being null.

Comment: it is only effective when the line begins with only one space:

Comment: @Rad1 What do you mean be "effective"? It also works with more than one space. That's what `trim()` is for.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) trim works for multiple characters and not only for space-char. @Rad1 may be you meant efficient, which depends on the implementation.

Comment: @Zhedar i mean when the buffer is reading the file , with trim if the line begins with one space it reads it , when more than one space it consider that the file is over and exit !

Comment: @Zhedar it is not a problem of space number , i think the text is too long for the buffer or something else it stops after a number of lines

Answer (score 1):

Sounds for me like you should use regular expressions (e.g. use the [String.matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method). They also can extract strings or substrings (see: [another Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560672/java-regex-to-extract-text-between-tags)).

There is also an excellent introduction by Lars Vogella about [regular expressions](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) in Java. Oracle compiled also a [Tutorial/Lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) about that topic.

May be this snippet helps a bit (uses [org.apache.commons.io.LineIterator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/LineIterator.html)):

```
public void grepLine(File file, String regex)
{
    LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file, "UTF-8");
    try
    {
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            String line = it.nextLine();
            if(line.matches(regex))
            {
                    //...do your stuff
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        LineIterator.closeQuietly(it);
    }
}
```

The regex might be something like (note: havn't checked it - especially the backslashes):

```
String regex="^\\s*if\\s+\\[\\s+\\\"\\$1\\\" = \\\""+config +"\\\" \\] ; then";
```

Answer (score 0):

Before all else: leave out DataInputStream, more Java Object specific.

```
boolean started = false;
while ...
    if (!started) {
        started = strLine.matches("\\s*...\\s*");
    } else {
        ...
```

Reg ex `\\s*` stand for zero or more white-space characters (tab, space).