# How to get a substring through regex in java android?

Tags: java, android, regex, expression

I have a text file that in it i have some text's that i must collect them. My text is like [this](https://gist.github.com/starbug1/6b8b531dc1228af00baf). I want to extract networks count,networks name and networks password. I tried to use regular expression but I do not know what expression i must use for this.Thanks for your helping.

Comment: could you share your try?

Comment: Post some code showing your attempt at the regular expression.

Comment: I tried to use [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560672/java-regex-to-extract-text-between-tags) but. i do not know how to use it exactly.

Comment: don't post more links... show your code implementation so far... so we can help you.

Comment: just public static void extractinfo(String config_file)
    {
        ArrayList<String> networkandinfo=new ArrayList<>();
 
    }

Comment: why you do not want to answer?:(

Comment: what is the network name, network count and network password in your link? 
I could not find the variables with these names.

Comment: this text file is wpa_supplicant.conf file in data/misc/wifi folder of phone or tablet. in this file networks info that device connect to them restored. sorry i mean SSID, PSK.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So to extract the ssid and psk from the file, you can try this :

```
ssid="([\w ]+)"|psk="([\w ]+)"
```

where it searches for

> -->ssid=" and extracts the content within the ". Similarly for the psk.

**There is a OR** between them so it will search for both the words. You can get the extracted data with the help of numbered groups.

PS: Do not forget to escape the characters.

Comment: well you can always upvote or accept the answer instead of thanks ;)